Tiling with one of each shape

Q. Is there a tiling of the plane by one each of simple polygons of $n$ vertices:
one triangle, one quadrilateral, one pentagon, $\ldots$ ,
one simple polygon of $n$ vertices, $\ldots$ ?

Here a vertex of a polygon is a point on its boundary with internal angle that differs from $\pi$.
I suspect the answer to Q is Yes but I am not seeing an explicit construction.

If the polygons don't have to be convex then you can just tile the plane with pentagons and divide each pentagon into two polygons of order n and n+1 (n=3,5,7,9,...) with a polygonal path.

@NoamD.Elkies: Brilliant---Thanks!

Might be impossible if all polygons must be convex.

I think it's still possible but the polygons get increasingly acicular.

Here is a picture (and extra characters to make it 30).


This should work for any sequence, not just 3, 4, 5, etc.   Each polygon must be of order at least 4 but triangles can always be combined to form higher-order polygons.

Yes, this is quite universal. I knew a modification of this construction to reach an arbitrarily large minimum degree of the underlying graph (1-skeleton).
